# Spark SQL for-loop error 'bool' attribute has no attribute 'alias'

Tags: python, for-loop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create new columns in a Spark SQL dataframe that compare two columns within the dataframe, and return True if they are equal and False otherwise. I have to do this for a datset with thousands of columns. To be a sample problem, I've included all of my code here. However, the important problem comes in the second `for` loop at the end of the code bloc.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *    
data = sc.parallelize([[1, None, 'BND'], [2, None, 'RMP'], [3, None, 'SWP'], [4, None, "IRS"], [5, None, "SWP"], [6, None, "IRS"]])
match = sc.parallelize([[1, 2,  100], [3, 5, 101], [4, 6, 102]])

trade_schema_string = 'trade_id,match_id,product'
trade_fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in trade_schema_string.split(',')]
trade_fields[0].dataType = IntegerType()
trade_fields[1].dataType = IntegerType()
trade_schema = StructType(trade_fields)

match_schema_string = "pri_netting_id,sec_netting_id,match_id"
match_fields = [StructField(field_name, IntegerType(), True) for field_name in match_schema_string.split(',')]
match_schema = StructType(match_fields)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, trade_schema)
odf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(match, match_schema)
df.registerTempTable("trade")
odf.registerTempTable("match")

# Get match_ids so you can match up front office and back office records
# Change column names for fo and bo dataframes so that they say "bo_product" and "fo_product", etc.
fo = sqlContext.sql("SELECT t.trade_id,t.product,m.match_id FROM trade t INNER JOIN match m WHERE t.trade_id = m.pri_netting_id")
bo = sqlContext.sql("SELECT t.trade_id,t.product,m.match_id FROM trade t INNER JOIN match m WHERE t.trade_id = m.sec_netting_id")
col_names = fo.columns
for x in range(0, len(col_names)):
    col_name = col_names[x]
    fo = fo.withColumnRenamed(col_name, "fo_" + col_name)
    bo = bo.withColumnRenamed(col_name, "bo_" + col_name)

fo.registerTempTable("front_office")
bo.registerTempTable("back_office")

fobo = sqlContext.sql("SELECT f.fo_trade_id,f.fo_product,b.bo_trade_id,b.bo_product FROM front_office f INNER JOIN back_office b WHERE f.fo_match_id = b.bo_match_id")
fobo = fobo.repartion(5)
# How to create diff columns
num_cols = len(fobo.columns)
fobo_names = fobo.columns
first = fobo.first()

for x in range(0, num_cols / 2):
    new_name = "\'diff_" + fobo_names[x][3:] + "\'"
    old_column_fo = "fobo." + fobo_names[x]
    old_column_bo = "fobo." + fobo_names[x + (num_cols / 2)]
    fobo = fobo.withColumn(new_name, old_column_fo == old_column_bo)
```

The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 8, in 
>     File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 695, in withColumn
>       return self.select('*', col.alias(colName))
>   AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'alias'

So, the strange thing is that if I execute the following by hand:

`fobo = fobo.withColumn("diff_product", fobo.fo_product == fobo.bo_product)`

and

`fobo = fobo.withColumn("diff_trade_id", fobo.fo_trade_id == fobo.bo_trade_id)`

The whole thing works perfectly. However, this isn't practical for my true use case, which has many columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
old_column_fo = "fobo." + fobo_names[x]
old_column_bo = "fobo." + fobo_names[x + (num_cols / 2)]
fobo = fobo.withColumn(new_name, old_column_fo == old_column_bo)
```

`old_column_fo` and `old_column_bo` will be strings that merely *look* like the attribute names you're trying to access, but they won't be the actual attributes. Try using `getattr` instead.

```
old_column_fo = getattr(fobo, fobo_names[x])
old_column_bo = getattr(fobo, fobo_names[x + (num_cols / 2)])
fobo = fobo.withColumn(new_name, old_column_fo == old_column_bo)
```

Comment: thanks @kevin! That worked. Can I ask, what is the difference (under the hood) between a string that 'looks like' the attribute name and the attribute name itself? Is there a way to analyze `type(foo)` to see if I'm grabbing the actual attribute or just some unworkable representation of it?